# The selected type is not visible and cannot be run by Pex

Tags: moles, pex

I'm running Pex 1.4.40602.0.  When I try to run Pex on an internal" type I get a "The selected type is not visible and cannot be run by Pex." error dialog.  I have tried to place the following commands in my Assembly.cs file, but all to no avail:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Groucho.Generic.Tests")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Groucho.Generic.Moles")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Groucho.Generic.Explorables")]
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Have you tried cleaning all projects, and then rebuild each individually, in order? This sometimes helps get things unstuck.